# Variables inside functions inside functions in javascript? (with async calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the JIT and making a spacetree, but the data the server returns isn't in the proper format, so I figured it would be easiest to just build a string that IS the right format and then parse that with eval (which works fine). The problem now comes in that I need to use another string of JSON that isn't in the right format to add children nodes to the space tree, and I now have no idea what I'm doing. Here's my code:

```
function grabdata(empid, fname, lname){
    var json = ''; 
    jQuery.getJSON('../../Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        for(var i=data.DATA.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            json = json + 'id: "' + data.DATA[i][3] + '",name: "' + data.DATA[i][0] + ' ' + data.DATA[i][1] + '",data: {},children: [{';
        }
        json = json + 'id: "' + empid + '",name: "' + fname + ' ' + lname + '",data: {},children: [';
        alert("JSON 1: " + json);
        jQuery.getJSON('../../Mobile_Subordinate.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data2) { 
            console.log(data2);
            for(var i=0; i<data2.DATA.length; i++){
                json = json + '{id: "' + data2.DATA[i][4] + '",name: "' + data2.DATA[i][0] + ' ' + data2.DATA[i][1] + '",data: {},children: []},';
            }
            alert("JSON 2: " + json);
        });
        json = json + ']';
        for(var i=data.DATA.length; i>0; i--){
            json = json + '}]';
        }
        alert("JSON 3: " + json);
    });
}
```

Here's what I'm getting from the alerts, and what my goal is:

```
JSON 1: id: "000-25-9687",name: "NAME1          LNAME1                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-91-3619",name: "FNAME2            LNAME2                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-01-2302",name: "FNAME3            LNAME3                    ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-14-7189",name: "FNAME4           LNAME4                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-62-7276",name: "FNAME5 LNAME5",data: {},children: [

JSON 2: id: "000-25-9687",name: "NAME1          LNAME1                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-91-3619",name: "FNAME2            LNAME2                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-01-2302",name: "FNAME3            LNAME3                    ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-14-7189",name: "FNAME4           LNAME4                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-62-7276",name: "FNAME5 LNAME5",data: {},children: []}]}]}]}]{id: "000-21-6506     ",name: "CHILD1          CHILDLNAME1                    ",data: {},children: []},{id: "000-17-7989     ",name: "CHILD2          CHILDLNAME2                   ",data: {},children: []},{id: "000-23-6712     ",name: "CHILD3        CHILDLNAME3              ",data: {},children: []},

JSON 3: id: "000-25-9687",name: "NAME1          LNAME1                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-91-3619",name: "FNAME2            LNAME2                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-01-2302",name: "FNAME3            LNAME3                    ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-14-7189",name: "FNAME4           LNAME4                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-62-7276",name: "FNAME5 LNAME5",data: {},children: []}]}]}]}]

JSON 4: id: "000-25-9687",name: "NAME1          LNAME1                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-91-3619",name: "FNAME2            LNAME2                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-01-2302",name: "FNAME3            LNAME3                    ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-14-7189",name: "FNAME4           LNAME4                  ",data: {},children: [{id: "000-62-7276",name: "FNAME5 LNAME5",data: {},children: [{id: "000-21-6506     ",name: "CHILD1          CHILDLNAME1                    ",data: {},children: []},{id: "000-17-7989     ",name: "CHILD2          CHILDLNAME2                   ",data: {},children: []},{id: "000-23-6712     ",name: "CHILD3        CHILDLNAME3              ",data: {},children: []},]}]}]}]}]
```

Obviously it's moving on past and doing what makes the JSON3 alert before it has time to grab and build the JSON2 alert. How do I make it stop and wait for that getJSON call to finish and the success function to finish before it goes on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, if you're making an asynchronous call (like `jQuery.getJSON`), anything in the script **after** that call is going to be executed **before** the asynchronous call completes.

If you want to keep things crsytal clear, you can write your code like this:

```
function grabdata(empid, fname, lname){
    jQuery.getJSON('../../Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data) {
        jQuery.getJSON('../../Mobile_Subordinate.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data2) { 

            // DO ALL YOUR STUFF WITH data AND data2 HERE

        });
    });
}
```

It's not optimal, but it's clear that both AJAX calls must complete before the code in the innermost block will execute.

---

If you're looking as more advanced handling of multiple concurrent ajax requests, you can create a promise that executes on the completion of two asynce requests with [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Here's an example:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('../../Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm?Empid='+empid),
    $.getJSON('../../Mobile_Subordinate.cfm?Empid='+empid)
).done(function (data, data2){

            // DO ALL YOUR STUFF WITH data AND data2 HERE

});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for what I needed, will look into $.when() *when* I need it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding you correctly here:  you need to make two calls to the server

- Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm?Empid=
- Mobile_Subordinate.cfm?Empid=

These two calls are independent of each other, it doen't matter which one you
do first. The data returned by both needs to be processed and combined into a string. The basic structure of you code is

```
1 function grabdata(...){
2    // this variable is availabe to all functions
3    var json = ''; 
4    jQuery.getJSON('Mobile_ReportingChain.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data) {
5        // when data from Mobile_ReportingChain finally arrives: process  and add to var json:
6        json = json + ....
7
8        jQuery.getJSON('Mobile_Subordinate.cfm?Empid='+empid, function(data2) { 
9             // when data from Mobile_Subordinate finally arrives: process  and add to var json:
10            json = json + ....
11       });
12
13        // add some more stuff from Mobile_ReportingChain data to json
14        json = json + '.....
15    });
16 }
```

You have two asynchronous calls here, so the actual order this will happen is might be:

- 1, 2, 3, 4 (async call to Mobile_ReportingChain), 16. done. function
  returns, var json is lost forever

seconds later, when data from Mobile_ReportingChain finally arrives:

- 5, 6, 7, 8 (async call to Mobile_Subordinate), 13, 14. function
  returns.

seconds later, when data from Mobile_Subordinate finally arrives:

- 9, 10, function returns.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/dSyw5/) where you can try it out for real.

jQuery offers deferred objects, when + then to handle this situation:

```
function grabdata() {

    $.when($.ajax(url1), $.ajax(url2)).then(

    function(d1, d2) {
        console.log('both calles returned');
        console.log('call 1 returned ' + d1[0].length + ' bytes of data');
        console.log('call 2 returned ' + d2[0].length + ' bytes of data');

        // here is where you do more stuff with the data

    });

    console.log('at the end of grabdata().');
    // nothing intresing to do, nothing to return

}
```

Again: [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/H2qaU/) to try it out.